# перенос текста "блоками"

Tags: css

делаю мобильную версию.

есть строка, которая выглядит вот так:
[image]

перенос - тегом `br`. это нормальный вид, но если телефон немного уже, то начинают переноситься слова, выглядит это вот так:

### [image]

мне нужно что бы на втором скрине текст был в одну строку.
если убрать `br`, то будет то что нужно, но тогда на широких экранах этот текст будет в одну строку, а не как на 1м скрине.
при этом желательно без `wbr` или подобного, старые браузеры тоже должны это поддерживать.

как быть?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space

Comment: пробовал, это не подходит из за того что принимается за "блок" фраза "на e-mail", а с white-space текст переносится и на дефисе, и без предлога "на".

Comment: пример кода где ? мне не ясно что вы делали и где именно проблема

Comment: пример кода это просто строка, в отладчике поставить эмуляцию телефона и эта проблема сразу будет видна. я пытаюсь добиться переноса текста как я описал, т.е. что бы не разрывалась фраза "на e-mail" и текст был максимум в 2 строки

Comment: медиа запросы  https://itchief.ru/lessons/html-and-css/css-media-queries убираешь br через display:none на том разрешение которое тебе надо, ну и там манипулируешь всем чем надо.

Comment: слушай Тёска .... помести этот пример в тег "p" и стилизуй его как угодно ... width и прочие css селекторы работают и так же медиа запросы -для любого устройства можно сделать что угодно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких br wbr и прочего не применял вообще ..на всех экранах будет выглядеть одинаково ...

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.post{
  padding:20px;
}
p{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
p{

  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight:900;
  font-family:Helvetica;
  width:45%;
  margin:auto;
}

@media (max-width:560px){
  p{
font-size:1em;
width:80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="post">
  <p>Отправка результатов платежа
    <p>
      <p class="last"> по email</p>
</div>
```